# Thousand seperator - format excel cell using XLConnect and R

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I export tables with large values to .xlsx using XLConnect.

Is there a way for the results to be written into an excel-cell with activated thousand separators?

```
library(XLConnect)
#example for a large value
a <- 10000000000

wb <- loadWorkbook("sof_q.xlsx"), create = TRUE)
    cs <- createCellStyle(wb)
    setDataFormat(cs, format = "0.00")
createSheet(wb, name = "a")
writeWorksheet(wb,a,"a",startRow = 1, startCol = 1, header = TRUE)
    rc = expand.grid(row = 1:2, col = 1:2)
    setCellStyle(wb, sheet = "a", row = rc$row, col = rc$col, cellstyle = cs)
    setColumnWidth(wb, sheet = "a", column = 1:5, width = -1)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

In Excel, `a` should look like this

```
10.000.000.000
```

Using

```
setDataFormat(cs, format = "0,000,000.00")
```

might work but in the case of shorter values, I have values like

```
0,032,666.29
```

Comment: You can use `prettyNum` in R as `prettyNum(a, big.mark='.', scientific=F)` but this will create a character field in R which will also be exported as such in excel.

Comment: @LytandeR thx - as you said - not perfect under these circumstances, but it is good to know that this function exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use # for a digit placeholder:

```
setDataFormat(cs, format = "###,###.00")
```

or

```
setDataFormat(cs, format = "###,##0")
```

Comment: in my case, `setDataFormat(cs, format = "###,##0.00")` works best. thx